# Logger not functioning properly

Tags: java, logging

I am using `java.util.logging.Logger` Class for logging in my application. I have added FileHandler so that the application log is stored directly in log.txt file.

But for some reason, after the application is terminated the log is far from complete. On cmd, I can see all the statements but they are never appended to the file.

I have set FileHandler to the Logger by:

```
private void setLogger() {
    try {
        FileHandler hand = new FileHandler("log/log.txt", true);
        hand.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ImageRename.MAIN_LOG);
        //log.setUseParentHandlers(false);
        log.addHandler(hand);
        log.setLevel(Level.ALL);          
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could Not set logger");
    }
}
```

Any problem with flushing? How to solve it? Thanks.

PS: On debugging, I have noticed that in between

> Logger.getLogger(ImageRename.MAIN_LOG).getHandlers().length

returns 0. Where as it should return 1. Initially it was printing 1, but somewhere down the line it becomes zero.

Comment: I think one of the best ways to deal with your logging is to work with [Apache log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/). This is one easy to use and highly customizable logging framework for Java

Comment: Avoid library bloat. I see little benefit of log4j over *current* Java logging (introduced in Java 1.4).

Comment: Try logging at highest priority, and try setting a level for the *handler*. Probably your handler is not set up to log at this level.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Tried that. Didnt help

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: While this is debatable and off-topic, I don't quite agree that using log4j is quite a library bloat. It's true that you can create your own logging framework using Java logging but why turn the wheel when something is available off the shelf that does not significantly incur any performance cost

Comment: True. But in this case Logger is giving a tough time :)

Comment: @Sujay `java.util.logging` is a *complete* logging framework. You do not need to create *anything*, it's included with Java off-the-shelf. It just didn't exist **before Java 1.4**, when log4j was created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is ... **garbage collection**.

What is happening is likely the following:

1. You call `Logger.getLogger(ImageRename.MAIN_LOG);`
2. You setup the logger.
3. Java notices it is unreferenced, and discards it.
4. You call `Logger.getLogger(ImageRename.MAIN_LOG);` and expect to get the same logger.
5. A *fresh* logger is set up with default configuration.

You can avoid this by two measures:

- Use a configuration file `logging.properties` for configuration. When creating the logger, the Java logging API will consult the configuration, and thus recreate it appropriately.
- Use static references. This is a best practise anyway. Equip each class with a logger:

  ```
  private final static Logger LOG =
      Logger.getLogger(ExampleClass.class.getName());
  ```

While the class is loaded it then should not be garbage collected AFAICT.

Answer (score 1):

See e.g. http://www.massapi.com/class/fi/FileHandler.html for an example (found via Google)

Note the following line, which may be your problem:

```
fileHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
```

(Note: this is the level of the `Handler`, not of the `Logger` or message.)

For debugging, first try to get messages at an `ERROR` level logged. Messages at level `INFO` and below are often supressed by default.

Also try setting the logging level as soon as possible. In my experience, the most reliable way of configuring Java logging is by using a properties file, and invoking Java with:

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=path/to/file/logging.properties
```

The reason is that the settings you do sometimes are *not* applied to loggers created *before* you loaded the settings, once some changes have been made to the logging.

Comment: all my logs are of Info level. can you please what you mean by "Messages at level INFO and below are often supressed by default."

Comment: +1 for using properties file for configuring your logger. Also I would suggest using the predefined levels rather than "All". In this case setting `Level.FINE` or even `Level.FINEST` would be helpful

Comment: Sorry, I thought the default level was to log only *above* `INFO`, but as far as I can tell it is to start logging at `INFO` itself. Then you should be seeing them. Anyway, try logging at higher level for debugging!

Comment: I tried it with fileHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL);, still it doesnt work. While debugging I have noticed that the handler gets dissappeared in btw. I do not know how.

Comment: How did you test that it disappeared? Did you add it to the proper logger? And seriously *try using the `.properties` file*!

Comment: In btw, I called a function at different places to check that.